# How can I apply some operations to a pair of rows and store the value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate a number (similarity) between a pair of registers (rows) and register the result in a column cell for each row.

I have a data frame like the one below:

```
id  age height  weight  similarity  most_similar
0   12.0    155.0   40.0    NaN NaN
1   24.0    175.0   65.0    NaN NaN
2   20.0    180.0   69.0    NaN NaN
3   24.0    160.0   60.0    NaN NaN
4   12.0    150.0   60.0    NaN NaN
```

Then I want to calculate the similarity to every pair of rows, discover the most similar row to each one and register this value.

The similarity will check if two values are equal, age == age, and if this is the case, it will sum points to the similarity.

For id 0, similarity to row 1 is 0, no value is equal, row 2 is 0, row 3 is 0, but row 4 has 1 point since age is equal. I'd store the value at the similarity column for row 4. Before going to the new row used as an index, I'd check which similarity is higher and I'd store the id of the higher row in the most_similar column for id == 0.

The process goes over the whole table.

The result will be the most_similar column filled with the element that has the highest similarity value for each row.

Comment: Hi Dan, in the future do not 'stylize' your example data, it just makes it harder to use tools like `pd.read_clipboard()` in order to parse it (because of the '|', '...' and so on). Just copy paste the example, or even better - just write the piece of code that creates it.

Comment: Also, when giving example data - also give the example expected output. For example, I don't understand what the `similarity` column should hold in this example - I'm not sure you need it though.

Comment: Hi Itamar, thanks for the heads up. I invented the dataset. The similarity function compares two rows and according to the number of parameters that are equal, gives a number of points. For example. If age is equal in both rows, we sum one point. If height is equal, we add another point. Same for weight. So 3 is the maximum output for the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is based on *Numpy* (which allows much quicker processing),
so the first step is to extract the underlying *Numpy* array:

```
tbl = df.values
```

As *id* column is the index, *tbl* contains only "other" (remaining) columns.

The first actual processing step is to calculte the differences between rows
(similarity matrix):

```
diffs = tbl[np.newaxis, :, :] - tbl[:, np.newaxis, :]
diffs2 = tbl.shape[1] - np.count_nonzero(diffs, axis=2)
```

The result (for your sample data) is:

```
array([[3, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 3, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

But we are not interested in similiraty of a row to itself,
so the diagonal elements should be replaced with zeroes:

```
np.fill_diagonal(diffs2, 0)
```

The result (*diffs2*) is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Notice however that if a row contains **only** zeroes then
this row has **nothing** in common with any other row.
So we should:

- compute a mask for rows that have at least one non-zero element,
- find indices of max element in each row,
- "filter" them with the above mask, to change values from "wrong"
  rows into *-1* (my choice, to not change *int* type of the result),
- save the resulting (1-D) array as *most_similar* column in the target
  DataFrame.

The code is:

```
msk = diffs2.max(axis=0) > 0
df['most_similar'] = np.where(msk, diffs2.argmax(axis=0), -1)
```

Note also that the solution by *Itamar Mushkin* has such a flaw that:

- for row 2 it computes the most similar row as *0*,
- whereas *no row* has something in common with row 2.

And as far as execution speed is concerned, I compared the execution time of
both solutions. But due to execution of the test in a loop, the source
DataFrame should not change. So:

- I copied *df* to *df1* (where the column will be added),
- wrote a function containing my solution, but ending with
  *df2['most_similar'] = ...* (note **df2** instead of *df*),
- the same for solution by *Itamar*,
- then I measured execution time of both these functions with *%timeit*.

Try the above procedure yourself and you will see, on your own,
how many times my solution is quicker.

## Edit

If you want to have also *similarity* column, then run:

```
tbl = df.values
diffs = tbl.shape[1] - np.count_nonzero(
    tbl[np.newaxis, :, :] - tbl[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=2)
np.fill_diagonal(diffs, 0)
sim = diffs.max(axis=0)  # Max similarity
df['similarity'] = sim
df['most_similar'] = np.where(sim > 0, diffs.argmax(axis=0), -1)
```

To measure the execution time with *%timeit* change *df* to *df2* in two
last instructions.

## Edit 2

**In response to you additional question in a comment:**

As we perform **numeric** subtraction, all 3 compared columns should be
numbers. If they are not, you should convert them to numbers.

One of possible reasons that you have **text** content may be that the actual
value may be **not known** and this may be marked in source data as some text
(or at least something not convertible to a number).

So before you begin processing, each such value should be converted to *NaN*
and each column should have *float64* type (not *object*).

Then the *Numpy* table still has *float64* type.

I made a test, changing *24.0* in row with *id == 3* to *NaN* and got
the following result:

```
     age  height  weight  similarity  most_similar
id                                                
0   12.0   155.0    40.0           1             4
1   24.0   175.0    65.0           0            -1
2   20.0   180.0    69.0           0            -1
3    NaN   160.0    60.0           1             4
4   12.0   150.0    60.0           1             0
```

Comparing to the "original" result, there are the following differences:

- Row *1* has similarity *0*. Before it had *1* - equality in *age* with
  row *3*.
- Row *3* has still similarity *1*, but this time with row *4*, due to
  equal *weight*.

So as you can see, my solution works also in case of *NaN* values in
source data.
When one of arguments is *NaN* (or both), the subtraction gives also *NaN*
result.
Then, during counting *3 - # of non-zero values*, such *NaN* result will also
not be taken into account.

Comment: Hi @Valdi_Bo, really nice approach! I like the reasoning. One question, what if one of the columns we are comparing has a text input. Would we make a transformation of each different text to be represented by a number and then process like you did?

Comment: I added answer in "Edit 2". I wrote also a little about cases of *NaN* in source data (too much text to fit in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no escaping a single call to `.iterrows()`, but we can avoid another one by trying out best to use `pandas` functions which are more optimized for performance:

```
def max_and_idxmax_similarity(df, index, row):
    x = (df.drop(index) == row).sum(axis=1)
    return x.max(), x.idxmax()

df[['similarity', 'most_similar']] = [max_and_idxmax_similarity(df, index, row) for index, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: The matrix will compute all the values. I just need the maximum (in case of a tie, lowest ID). The function is necessary because there are more calculations that I left out of the specification for the matter of simplicity.

The eight of each attribute being equal varies.

Comment: My previous approach was a "traditional" one, meaning, I went over the whole matrix to calculate similarity iterating using iterrows, which doesn't seem to be the fastest way.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function is necessary"? which function? Are you trying to say that you want to store both the value of the (maximal) similarity and the index of the maximum? (I've edited my answer assuming that's what you mean)

Comment: Also, I think this version will be faster - using vectorized operations instead of loops usually is.